# Rest-client ruby gem attached 0 kb file

Tags: ruby, rest-client

I'm using `rest-client` ruby gem to upload an HTML document through an API. Every time I execute my code, the attachment got uploaded with the file name but the file is empty (0 Kb). Below is my Ruby code.

I have tried with `file.open` also, but the result is same.

```
require 'rest-client'

temp_url = "https://example.com/api/123/456/blob-handles"

response = RestClient::Request.execute(
  method: :post,
  url: temp_url,
  headers: { 
    :authorization => 'Bearer e268ff75-et5e-49t6-bba0',
    :file_name => 'test',
    :content_type => 'text/html',
    :body => { 
      :upload => File.new('D:/Demo/Automation/reports/Regression_Execution_Report', 'rb')
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: pls help me solve this issue.